# How do you encode XML safely with ActionScript 3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I'm capturing data from the user and writing it to an xml string like so:

var myXml:XML = 
   
      {userEnteredText}

This is fine and dandy until the user gets cute with special characters like "& < >" etc.  Illegal characters are also a problem like 0x19.

Is there are method that will sanatize my xml and encode special characters or will I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply converting the string to a textnode should do the trick

```
var s:String = "test<ie>test";
var x:XML = <xml/>;
x.appendChild(s);
trace(x.toXMLString());//outputs "<xml>test&lt;ie&gt;test</xml>"
```

also, you can stuff all the content into [CTADA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cdata#CDATA_sections_in_XML) ...

i'm not sure, why 0x19 should be illegal ... whitespaces and nullbytes are often dropped ... but if it is binary data you want, you should probably use [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) ... [>here's a lib<](http://dynamicflash.com/goodies/base64/)

Answer (score 3):

This *does* work, however:

```
var s:String = "test<ie>test";
var x:XML = <xml>{s}</xml>;
Alert.show(x.toXMLString());
```

And this shows up in the Alert: `<xml>test&lt;ie&gt;test</xml>`

Got it from [Adobe's doc: Assembling and transforming XML objects](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=13_Working_with_XML_07.html)

Answer (score 1):

The [top level function](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/package.html#escape()) `escape` is one approach to this.

Comment: Except that this escape spaces as %20, which, unless you're then doing a similar conversion on the client side, is not automatically unescaped.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a comment to back2dos' suggestion:

```
var s:String = "test<ie>test";
var x:XML = <xml/>;
x.appendChild(s);
trace(x.toXMLString());//outputs "<xml>test&lt;ie&gt;test</xml>"
```

On my machine, trying this generated the exception:

```
An ActionScript error has occurred:
TypeError: Error #1085: The element type "ie" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</ie>".
```

So I'm still looking for the answer to the exact same question.

Sorry, but I don't yet have 100 points, so I can't comment directly on that post yet.