# How do I html encode text inside Action Script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, html-parsing, html-encode

I have an app that builds XML, the text nodes values are coming from the users.
How would I HTML encode that input to avoid bad characters?
Preferably looking for a built in solution in Action Script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used `escape()` and `unescape()` for POST variables in the past, not sure if it's the best solution for XML though.

This method seems promising: http://www.markledford.com/blog/2009/02/25/as3-htmldecode-htmlencode-xml-hack/

You can also try converting the string to a textnode as mentioned in [How do you encode XML safely with ActionScript 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856726/how-do-you-encode-xml-safely-with-actionscript-3)